# Join em array criando elementos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, join

Podemos imaginar o seguinte `array`:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

Sei que posso usar o `join(", ")` para transformá-lo em uma string tipo: `"a, b, c, d"`, porém eu gostaria de criar um elemento para cada item do array, que ficasse tipo: `"<li>a</li> <li>b</li> <li>c</li> <li>d</li>"`, é possível fazer isso usando o `join()`?

Obs: Sei que também posso dar um loop e fazer isso usando outros métodos, eu só gostaria de reduzir código mesmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta combinar o `join` com o `map`:

```
const result = arr.map(it => `<li>${it}</li>`).join(' ')
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

const result = arr.map(it => `<li>${it}</li>`).join(' ')

console.log(result)
```

Ou com o `reduce`:

```js
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

const result = arr.reduce((res, it) => res + `<li>${it}</li>`, '')

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Precisa realmente do `map`?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters não é bem uma questão de necessidade - neste exemplo, mas fica mais simples por você trabalhar com o elemento separado. O que você fizer no `map` será refletido em todos. Pense que agora você precise colocar um `<a>` dentro do `<li>`.

Comment: Você tem razão. E dependendo da situação, eu apelaria até para um `document.createElement` para ficar mais elegante :p

Answer (score 3):

Assim?

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var html = "<li>" + arr.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";

console.log(html)
```

A ideia é você usar o `</li><li>` como o objeto de concatenação.

O `arr.join('</li><li>')` vai gerar isso:

```
 "1</li><li>2</li><li>3"
```

Sendo assim, basta adicionar `<li>` no início e `</li>` no final dessa `string` gerada pelo `join`.

Além do exemplo acima, daria para fazer algo mais elaborado, com `document.createElement`, para criar os `li` já dentro de uma `ul`, por exemplo:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];


var ul = document.createElement('ul');

arr.forEach(function (value) {

     var li = document.createElement('li');
     
     li.innerText = value;
     
     ul.append(li);
})



console.log(ul.outerHTML);
```